# Not able to print associated role with users in thymeleaf page

Tags: spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am new to spring boot, can someone help please!!

I have a controller that displays the settings page.

```
@GetMapping("/setting")
public String settings(Model model){
    List<User> user =  userDao.findAll();
    model.addAttribute("user", user);
    return "settings";
}
```

My query

```
 @Query(value = "SELECT * FROM users u left join user_role ur on u.id = ur.user_id",nativeQuery=true)

 List<User> findAll();
```

On render, the setting page looks like this.

[image]

I need to display user role like (Admin/Moderator etc) along with role ids

The mapping of user with role is many to many.

```
    @ManyToMany(cascade=CascadeType.MERGE)
    @JoinTable(
          name="user_role",
          joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="USER_ID", referencedColumnName="ID")},
          inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="ROLE_ID", referencedColumnName="ID")})
    private List<Role> roles;
```

In the setting page i am not able to get the value of role.

```
           <tbody>
                <tr th:each="u,iterator : ${user}">
                    <!-- <td th:text="${u.id}"></td> -->
                    <td th:text="${iterator.index+1}"></td>
                    <td th:text="${u.name}"></td>  
                     <td th:if="${u.isActive}"><span class="status text-success">&bull;</span> Active</td>
                    <td th:unless="${u.isActive}"><span class="status text-warning">&bull;</span> InActive</td>                     
                    <td>****need to get role here***</td>
                </tr>
           </tbody>
```

Comment: If the user has multiple roles, what role do you want to get? You can do something like `${u.roles.get(0).name}`.

Comment: one user can have only one role, this i tried it was giving exception

Comment: Why do you have a many to many relationship, then?

Comment: earlier design was as such, but it never came into effect

Comment: I would change it as it makes things like this easier

Comment: Btw, can you show the code of the `Role` class?

Comment: @ManyToMany(mappedBy="roles")
 private List<User> users;

Comment: @dan1st thnks for ur suggestion it was very good

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do something like this:

```
 <td><span th:each="role : ${u.roles}" th:text="${role.name}+' '"></span></td>
```

According in the Role class you have a name field.

The space at the end is just a separator in case you have multiple roles.